# Bedeutung von »Spiegel« in einem Beispielsatz

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet der erste Satz in diesem Text?

> Der Strom zog still seinen Weg und konnte keine Blumen und Zweige auf seinem **Spiegel** mitnehmen. <sup>A. v. Droste-Hülsoff: Ledwina</sup>

Bedeutet Spiegel hier Weg oder Destination oder was?

Comment: Please do not post text as a bitmap image - there still are people on low bandwidth.  In addition, a bitmap can not be indexed or searched. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Als den *Spiegel* eines Gewässers bezeichnet man die Oberfläche eines (meist stehenden) Gewässers, weil sich darin die Umgebung spiegelt.

[image: Spiegelnder See]
*<sup>See, in dem sich die Umgebung spiegelt.</sup>*

Auch die Oberfläche von Wasser z.B. in einem Gefäß bezeichnet man als *»Wasserspiegel«*.

Dass die Oberfläche von fließenden Gewässern auch *»Spiegel«* genannt wird, ist selten, weil sich wegen der ständigen verändernden Wellen kein statisches Spiegelbild bilden kann. In diesem Text wird das Wort *»Spiegel«* aber ohnehin in einem eher literarisch Sinn verwendet, um das schnöde Wort *»Oberfläche«* zu vermeiden.

Comment: Tolle Illustration; sehr eingängig. Dein Bild?  - Vielleicht sollte man noch dazu sagen, dass "Spiegel" in diesem Sinne eigentlich so gut wie nie verwendet wird. Außer von Dichtern, die sehr dichterisch klingen wollen.

Comment: Du hast noch nicht viele fließende Gewässer gesehen, oder? Die sind ja nun oft an manchen Stellen ruhig während sie an anderen unruhig sind.

Comment: @userunknown   Ich wäre vorsichtig, wenn es darum geht, einen Österreicher zu bezichtigen, er habe noch keine Fließgewässer gesehen. Im Zweifelsfall wohnt er direkt an der Donau...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Gerade die Donau hat breite, langsame Stellen die bei Windstille und richtigem Lichteinfall gefällig zu spiegeln wissen. https://www.google.de/search?q=donau&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=DbI&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlhe-7uYvfAhVeAxAIHeJjAN8Q_AUIDygC&biw=1280&bih=686

Comment: @userunknown  Wem sagst du das? Da brauche ich kein Gugel nicht dafür, bin ich doch einer der (nicht gar so vielen) Menschen, die buchstäblich jeden Meter der Donau von Tuttlingen bis Sulina mit eigenen Händen angefasst haben. Manche davon waren wellig, manche spiegelig, einige auch strudelig.

Comment: Ich habe ca. 20 Jahre lang in Wien gewohnt, davon 2 Jahre lang fast direkt an der Alten Donau. Die ist aber ein stehendes Gewässer. (Im 19. Jahrhundert war sie noch ein fließender Seitenarm der Donau.) Übrigens ist auch die Neue Donau ein stehendes Gewässer. Nur der Donaukanal, die Donau, die Liesing und die Wien sind Flüsse in Wien. Jetzt wohne ich aber in St. Pölten. Um diese unterschätzte Stadt machen viele einen Bogen, auch die Donau. Nur die Traisen fließt durch St. Pölten. Aufgewachsen bin ich in Graz (Fluss: Mur) und habe auch ein paar Jahre in Bruck a.d. Mur (Flüsse: Mur, Mürz) gelebt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke schön mein Lehrer. Am Anfang verstehe ich dass es auf die Oberfläche hinwiest aber dann denke ich dass es meint Destination oder ein selektiertes Ziel weil man ledeglich Oberfläche des Wassers nennen kann ohne die schwierige Sprache zu verwenden

Comment: Satz mit gleicher Konstruktion: »Der Lastkraftwagen fuhr und konnte keine Passagiere auf seiner Ladefläche mitnehmen.« Auch in diesem Satz wird kein Reiseziel erwähnt, sondern es wird nur ausgesagt, dass sich etwas (Blumen und Zweige bzw. Passagiere) nicht auf der Oberfläche des Transportmittels (Strom, Lastkraftwagen) befindet. Zur Klarstellung: Strom = großer Fluss (Nil, Amazonas, Jangtsekiang, Mississippi, Wolga, ...)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. Also, immer wenn ich in Wien an der Donau war, ist sie ziemlich stark geflossen. Am Abzweig des Kanals in Nußdorf, wo die riesige Schwarzpappel steht (steht sie noch?), sogar so stark, dass man schon einige Erfahrung braucht, da mit einer Ruderzille anzulegen. Stärkste Strömungslandung in ganz Österreich, die mir bekannt ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Es gibt in Wien 4 Gewässer, die den Namen »Donau« tragen. Eines heißt einfach nur »Donau« und ist ein großer schiffbarer Strom, der von Deutschland ins Schwarze Meer fließt. Bei Nußdorf zweigt nach rechts der Donaukanal ab, der bei Albern dann wieder in die Donau fließt. Diese beiden Gewässer sind fließend. Stehend sind: Die »Alte Donau« und die »Neue Donau«. Die Alte Donau wurde 1870-1875 von der Donau abgetrennt. Die Neue Donau entstand durch den Bau der Donauinsel in den Jahren 1972-1987. Sie ist 21 km lang, ca 200 m breit und verläuft parallel zur Donau.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: http://www.ganzi-design.at/files/ganzi_design/content/fotos/staedte/wien/wien0002.jpg links die »Neue Donau« (stehendes Gewässer, an dessen Ufern im Sommer tausende Wiener baden), rechts die »Donau«, die von Schiffen befahren wird und fließend ist. Dazwischen die 1972-1987 erbaute Donauinsel, auf der jedes Jahr im Sommer das größte Gratis-Musikfestival der Welt stattfindet. Der Südteil der Donauinsel ist übrigens zusammen mit der westlich angrenzenden Lobau auch eines der größten FKK-Gebiete Europas.

Answer (score 4):

Hier ist der Wasserspiegel, d. h. die Wasseroberfläche, gemeint, auf dem die Blumen und Zweige schwimmen und so durch den Strom transportiert werden.

Comment: Wer allerdings hat schon Blumen auf einem Fluss schwimmens sehen? Wenn schon dann Seerosen auf einem Teich...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich. <-- dies ist ein Füllkommentar -->

Comment: @userunknown  Möchtest du diese blumige Erfahrung mit etwas mehr Details ausgeschmückt teilen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ja, gerne: https://de.depositphotos.com/159711330/stock-video-wreath-of-flowers-floating-on.html

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Danke schön mein Lehrer. Am Anfang verstehe ich dass es auf die Oberfläche hinwiest aber dann denke ich dass es meint Destination oder ein selektiertes Ziel weil man ledeglich Oberfläche des Wassers nennen kann ohne die schwierige Sprache zu verwenden